# how to hide textfield validation without clicking on button in flutter

Tags: forms, flutter, validation, textfield

I have added validations on textfields using `Form`, it works perfectly on other screen, but in one screen it cause problem, when i navigate to that screen, without clicking on button it shows error message on textfields, i'm  just calling an api method in `initState()`. here is the code.

```
addproduct() {
    _formKey.currentState!.validate()
        ? showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return LoginSucessDailog(
                text: 'Your product is added successfully',
                title: 'Product Added',
              );
            })
        : print("error");}

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    init();
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
            child: Column(children: [
              SizedBox10(),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                    child: customImageButton(
                        context,
                        "+",
                        () {},
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
                        MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.13)),
              ),
              SizedBox20(),

              // Product name
              textformfieldCustomwithouticon(
                  context,
                  TextInputType.text,
                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                  productname, 
              //onchange
               (String value) {
                setState(() {
                  productname.text = value;
                });
              }, 
             //validator
             (value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'This is required field';
                }
                return null;
              },

// Add Product
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.07,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                            HexColor("#7367f0")),
                        shape:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                        ))),
                    onPressed: () {
                      addproduct();
                    },
                    child: Text('Add Product',
                        style: GoogleFonts.montserrat(fontSize: 20)),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox10(),
            ]),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

please help where i'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It has only some little change

```
autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
```

to

```
autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
```

or not write this argument autovalidateMode.

Comment: It works! but I need it to remove the error msg from textfield when I write something on it, how i can i achieve this without writing this?

Comment: @TimeToCode there are number of ways, remove the validation, make validation when the button is clicked```formkey.validate``` or change the input decoration of the error.